# Fourier Series of $sin^2(t)$

Tags: fourier-series

So, I know that $sin^2(t)$ is an even function so the $b_{n}$ co-efficient's are 0 and that we will only be figuring out the $a_{n}$ and the $a_{0}$ co-efficient's for the series and solving the integral.

The period of $sin^2(t)$ is $\pi$ so I use the interval,  $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

$$a_{n} = \int_{-\frac\pi2}^\frac\pi2 \sin^2(t)\cos(\frac{k\pi t}{\pi/2})dt$$

So, using the given expression for $a_{n}$ I reduce it to :

$$ a_{n} = \frac{1}{\pi} \left(\int_{-\frac\pi2}^\frac\pi2 cos(2t) dt - \int_{-\frac\pi2}^\frac\pi2 cos(2t)cos(2kt)dt \right)$$

The first integral  = 0,

For the second I find,

$$a_{n} = \frac{-1}{2\pi}\left( \frac{sin(\pi + \pi k)}{(k+1)} + \frac{sin(\pi - \pi k)}{(k-1)}   \right)$$
 But from here I don't know how I proceed to find the complete Fourier series, can anyone help me to finish the problem or to show any mistakes I've made or if there is a simpler way to do the integration.

Comment: $(1-\cos(2x))/2$, maybe?

Comment: So how did you get that?

Comment: Double angle identities.

Comment: Power reduction formulas from basic calculus days

Comment: Whats the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I changed it to the correct version.